# Почему в Виндовс 10 не загружается страница с экспертной системой на Javascript из-за антивируса?

Tags: javascript

Предыдущая версия, написанная другим человеком, состояла из нескольких файлов. Она имела недостаток, что работала только на ПК, а в браузере на Андроид нет. Не отображались чекбоксы и не нажимались кнопки. После объединения им же в один файл не получается скачивать из Виндовс 10 с Яндекс облака (ссылки в конце).
index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Рецепты</title>
        <style>
            hr {
             border: none; 
             background-color: black; 
             color: black; 
             height: 2px; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="input-container"></div>

        <button id="submit">Обработать</button>
        <button id="clear">Очистить</button>
        <button id="check-all">Выбрать всё</button>

        <p id="answer"></p>

        <script src="recipes.js"></script>
        <script src="ingredients.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
</code>

main.js
<code lang="javascript">

// функция переводит русские слова на латиницу это нужно для создания уникальных id для checkbox-ов 
function rus_to_latin ( str ) {
    
    var ru = {
        'а': 'a', 'б': 'b', 'в': 'v', 'г': 'g', 'д': 'd', 
        'е': 'e', 'ё': 'e', 'ж': 'j', 'з': 'z', 'и': 'i', 
        'к': 'k', 'л': 'l', 'м': 'm', 'н': 'n', 'о': 'o', 
        'п': 'p', 'р': 'r', 'с': 's', 'т': 't', 'у': 'u', 
        'ф': 'f', 'х': 'h', 'ц': 'c', 'ч': 'ch', 'ш': 'sh', 
        'щ': 'shch', 'ы': 'y', 'э': 'e', 'ю': 'u', 'я': 'ya',
    'ъ': 'ie', 'ь': '', 'й': 'i'
    }, n_str = [];
        
    for ( var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i ) {
       n_str.push(
              ru[ str[i] ]
           || ru[ str[i].toLowerCase() ] == undefined && str[i]
           || ru[ str[i].toLowerCase() ].replace(/^(.)/, function ( match ) { return match.toUpperCase() })
       );
    }
    
    return n_str.join('');
}

// рецепты
        const recipes = window.recipes; // все рецепты из полученного файла
        
        const button = document.querySelector("#submit");
        const answer = document.querySelector("#answer");

        // кнопка обработки. Не работает, пока не загружен файл
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            
            // список всех выбранных ингредиентов
            const selected = [...document.querySelectorAll("input[id]:checked")].map(
                (input) => input.id
            );
            answer.innerHTML = ""; // очистка ответа
            let lines = 0; 
            
            //сравнение массива выбранных ингредиентов с массивом всех ингредиентов
            let intersectionsList = []; 
            let intersections; 

            for (recipe of recipes) {

                intersections = recipe.ingredients.filter((item) => 
                selected.includes(rus_to_latin(item).toLowerCase())) 
                recipeIntersections = {"name": recipe.name, "intersections": intersections} // словарь {имя, пересечения}
                intersectionsList.push(recipeIntersections); // добавляем словарь в список

            }
            
            // сортировка
            intersectionsList.sort((a, b) => {
                return b.intersections.length-a.intersections.length;
            });

            // вывод на экран ингредиентов 
            
            for (i of intersectionsList) {

                if (i.intersections.length !== 0){
                let line = document.createElement("hr");
                let nextLine = document.createElement("br");
                answer.append(i.intersections.join(", ") + ": " + i.name);
                answer.append(nextLine);
                answer.append(line);
                lines++;

                }

            }   

            if (lines === 0){
                answer.innerHTML = "Таких рецептов нет!";
            }
        });

// ингредиенты
        let ingredients = window.ingredients;

        let inputContainer = document.getElementById("input-container")
        inputContainer.innerHTML = "";

        // вывод всех ингредиентов из файла

        for(let i = 0; i<ingredients.length; i++) {

            let ingredientCheckbox = document.createElement("input")
            ingredientCheckbox.id = rus_to_latin(ingredients[i]).toLowerCase();
            ingredientCheckbox.type = "checkbox"
            
            let ingredientLabel = document.createElement("label")
            ingredientLabel.for = ingredientCheckbox.id
            ingredientLabel.id = ingredientCheckbox.id + "-label"
            ingredientLabel.innerHTML = ingredients[i] + "\n"
            
            let nextLine = document.createElement("br")
            inputContainer.append(ingredientCheckbox);
            inputContainer.append(ingredientLabel);
            inputContainer.append(nextLine)

        }


// кнопка очистки выбора
let clearButton = document.getElementById("clear")
clearButton.addEventListener("click", () => {

    const selected = [...document.querySelectorAll("input[id]:checked")].map(
        (input) => input.id
    );

    for (ingredient of selected) {

        const getInput = document.getElementById(ingredient)
        getInput.checked = false;

    }

});
// кнопка "Выбрать все"
let checkAllButton = document.getElementById("check-all")
checkAllButton.addEventListener("click", () => {

    const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll("input[id]")].map(
        (input) => input.id
    );

    for (ingredient of inputs) {

        const getInput = document.getElementById(ingredient)
        getInput.checked = true;

    }

});
</code>

<code lang="javascript">
window.recipes = [
    {
        "name": "Пицца",
        "ingredients": [
            "Мука", "Вода", "Соль", "Колбаса", "Помидоры", "Соус"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Хлеб",
        "ingredients": ["Мука", "Вода", "Соль"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Кекс",
        "ingredients": ["Мука", "Вода", "Яйца", "Соль", "Сахар"]
    }
]
</code>

<code lang="javascript">
window.ingredients = [
        "Мука",
        "Вода",
        "Сахар",
        "Яйца",
        "Соль",
        "Колбаса", 
        "Помидоры",
        "Соус"
    ]
</code>

Так как нужно было, чтобы работало и в Андроид, человек объединил всё в один файл и после этого антивирус Виндовс 10 не стал пропускать этот файл через браузер на ПК, когда пытался скачать его.

index.html
<code lang="html">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Рецепты</title>
        <style>
            hr {
             border: none; 
             background-color: black; 
             color: black; 
             height: 2px; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
 
    <body>
        <div id="input-container"></div>
 
        <button id="submit">Обработать</button>
        <button id="clear">Очистить</button>
        <button id="check-all">Выбрать всё</button>
 
        <p id="answer"></p>
 
        <script>
window.recipes = [
    {
        "name": "Пицца",
        "ingredients": [
            "Мука", "Вода", "Соль", "Колбаса", "Помидоры", "Соус"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Хлеб",
        "ingredients": ["Мука", "Вода", "Соль"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Кекс",
        "ingredients": ["Мука", "Вода", "Яйца", "Соль", "Сахар"]
    }
]
 
window.ingredients = [
        "Мука",
        "Вода",
        "Сахар",
        "Яйца",
        "Соль",
        "Колбаса", 
        "Помидоры",
        "Соус"
    ]
 
// функция переводит русские слова на латиницу это нужно для создания уникальных id для checkbox-ов 
function rus_to_latin ( str ) {
    
    var ru = {
        'а': 'a', 'б': 'b', 'в': 'v', 'г': 'g', 'д': 'd', 
        'е': 'e', 'ё': 'e', 'ж': 'j', 'з': 'z', 'и': 'i', 
        'к': 'k', 'л': 'l', 'м': 'm', 'н': 'n', 'о': 'o', 
        'п': 'p', 'р': 'r', 'с': 's', 'т': 't', 'у': 'u', 
        'ф': 'f', 'х': 'h', 'ц': 'c', 'ч': 'ch', 'ш': 'sh', 
        'щ': 'shch', 'ы': 'y', 'э': 'e', 'ю': 'u', 'я': 'ya',
    'ъ': 'ie', 'ь': '', 'й': 'i'
    }, n_str = [];
        
    for ( var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i ) {
       n_str.push(
              ru[ str[i] ]
           || ru[ str[i].toLowerCase() ] == undefined && str[i]
           || ru[ str[i].toLowerCase() ].replace(/^(.)/, function ( match ) { return match.toUpperCase() })
       );
    }
    
    return n_str.join('');
}
 
// рецепты
        const recipes = window.recipes; // все рецепты из полученного файла
        
        const button = document.querySelector("#submit");
        const answer = document.querySelector("#answer");
 
        // кнопка обработки. Не работает, пока не загружен файл
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            
            // список всех выбранных ингредиентов
            const selected = [...document.querySelectorAll("input[id]:checked")].map(
                (input) => input.id
            );
            answer.innerHTML = ""; // очистка ответа
            let lines = 0; 
            
            //сравнение массива выбранных ингредиентов с массивом всех ингредиентов
            let intersectionsList = []; 
            let intersections; 
 
            for (recipe of recipes) {
 
                intersections = recipe.ingredients.filter((item) => 
                selected.includes(rus_to_latin(item).toLowerCase())) 
                recipeIntersections = {"name": recipe.name, "intersections": intersections} // словарь {имя, пересечения}
                intersectionsList.push(recipeIntersections); // добавляем словарь в список
 
            }
            
            // сортировка
            intersectionsList.sort((a, b) => {
                return b.intersections.length-a.intersections.length;
            });
 
            // вывод на экран ингредиентов 
            
            for (i of intersectionsList) {
 
                if (i.intersections.length !== 0){
                let line = document.createElement("hr");
                let nextLine = document.createElement("br");
                answer.append(i.intersections.join(", ") + ": " + i.name);
                answer.append(nextLine);
                answer.append(line);
                lines++;
 
                }
 
            }   
 
            if (lines === 0){
                answer.innerHTML = "Таких рецептов нет!";
            }
        });
 
// ингредиенты
        let ingredients = window.ingredients;
 
        let inputContainer = document.getElementById("input-container")
        inputContainer.innerHTML = "";
 
        // вывод всех ингредиентов из файла
 
        for(let i = 0; i<ingredients.length; i++) {
 
            let ingredientCheckbox = document.createElement("input")
            ingredientCheckbox.id = rus_to_latin(ingredients[i]).toLowerCase();
            ingredientCheckbox.type = "checkbox"
            
            let ingredientLabel = document.createElement("label")
            ingredientLabel.for = ingredientCheckbox.id
            ingredientLabel.id = ingredientCheckbox.id + "-label"
            ingredientLabel.innerHTML = ingredients[i] + "\n"
            
            let nextLine = document.createElement("br")
            inputContainer.append(ingredientCheckbox);
            inputContainer.append(ingredientLabel);
            inputContainer.append(nextLine)
 
        }
 
 
// кнопка очистки выбора
let clearButton = document.getElementById("clear")
clearButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
 
    const selected = [...document.querySelectorAll("input[id]:checked")].map(
        (input) => input.id
    );
 
    for (ingredient of selected) {
 
        const getInput = document.getElementById(ingredient)
        getInput.checked = false;
 
    }
 
});
// кнопка "Выбрать все"
let checkAllButton = document.getElementById("check-all")
checkAllButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
 
    const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll("input[id]")].map(
        (input) => input.id
    );
 
    for (ingredient of inputs) {
 
        const getInput = document.getElementById(ingredient)
        getInput.checked = true;
 
    }
 
});
        </script>
    </body>
 
</html>
```

Прошу поправить, чтобы не было проблемы.

Ссылка на код одним файлом в архиве, который не мог скачать из Виндовс (перегружался в Линукс) https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Q3zx2KZFWXdg0w

Предыдущая версия, до объединения в один файл https://disk.yandex.ru/d/rasHcsA_v5iDgw

Comment: Не очень понятно, как объединение кода в один файл может решить проблему с нерабочим чекбоксом и кнопками на Андроиде, конечно, если в процессе объединения недостатки в коде не были исправлены. Попробуйте временно отключить антивирус и скачать файл, либо же попробуйте скачать файл не zip, а rar архивом, не знаю насколько это поможет.

Comment: Код до объединения можно скачать по ссылке и обратить внимание на нюансы, которые делают кнопки работоспособными после объединения. Сам я не разбираюсь, поэтому попросил помощи здесь. Файл скачивал через Линукс, поэтому код привел здесь. Раз привел код, соответственно скачал уже и нет смысла скачивать rar архивом и отключать антивирус.